# Counting elements by row with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, summarize

I have a dataset where the data was provided in a format that isn't particularly useful.  Here is a smaller example:

You have a deck of cards, and ten cards are dealt, and the cards are recorded, and the process is repeated 5 times, and stored in a 5x10 matrix.  For simplicity, we will just number the cards 1-13 rather than Ace,1,2...King; with four copies of each card, not concerned with their suits.

```
set.seed(7)
tmpdf=data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=10))

for(i in 1:nrow(tmpdf)) {
    tmpdf[i,]=sample(rep(c(1:13),each=4),size=10)
}
```

```
> tmpdf
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1 13  6  2  1  3 10  4 11  2   5
2  3  3 10  2  6  1  7  1 11   4
3  9  4 13 12 12  1  8  6 11  13
4  9  4  3 13  5 10  6 13 10   5
5 11  5 10  6 11  4  1 10 10  13
```

The column of each card is not important, but how many copies of each card dealt to each hand is.  I know how to reorganize this in base R in a loop, but not the tidy way.

```
newdf=data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=13))
names(newdf)=as.character(c(1:13))

for(i in 1:nrow(tmpdf)) {
    tmp=table(factor(as.numeric(tmpdf[i,])))
    newdf[i,names(tmp)]=tmp
}
```

```
> newdf
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0  1  1  0  1
2 2 1 2 1 0 1 1 0 0  1  1  0  0
3 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1  0  1  2  2
4 0 0 1 1 2 1 0 0 1  2  0  0  2
5 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0  3  2  0  1
```

I suspected count and/or summarize would have been useful, but I have thus far been unable to develop a solution, nor find a question/answer here.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to go from tmpdf to newdf using tidy analysis principles?

Comment: It seems that newdf is not in tidy format, so I'm confused about why you'd care if intermediate steps use tidy principles.

Comment: I am surprised the new data frame isn't considered tidy- each row is an observation (hand) and each column is a variable (how many cards of a given type are in that hand?).  But yes, I am trying to get tmpdf into tidy format where we know how many of a given card are in each hand.  If the newdf is not actually tidy format, then I would prefer to know how to make it truly tidy.

Comment: I had been thinking that I would call each card an observation, and hand would be a variable to be grouped by, so I would have said that you'd need two columns, column 1 being hand number (a value 1 through 5) and column 2 being a number 1 through 13. There then would be 50 rows, one for each card. I think that that is similar to what @CPak does below. Thanks for asking this question and promoting the discussion!

Answer (score 1):

Not the `tidy` way, but maybe useful to you anyway since it is pretty brief:

```
data.frame(sapply(1:13,function(x) {rowSums(tmpdf==x)}))
```

Output:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13
1  1  2  1  1  1  1  0  0  0   1   1   0   1
2  2  1  2  1  0  1  1  0  0   1   1   0   0
3  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   0   1   2   2
4  0  0  1  1  2  1  0  0  1   2   0   0   2
5  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0   3   2   0   1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One tidy approach is to `tidyr::gather` all your values, `dplyr::count` them, then `tidyr::spread` them

```
tmpdf %>%
  group_by(rn = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, X1:X10) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(rn, value) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  spread(value, n, fill=0)

  # A tibble: 5 x 14
         # rn   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`  `13`
    # * <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    # 1     1  1.00  2.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  0     0     0     1.00  1.00  0     1.00
    # 2     2  2.00  1.00  2.00  1.00  0     1.00  1.00  0     0     1.00  1.00  0     0   
    # 3     3  1.00  0     0     1.00  0     1.00  0     1.00  1.00  0     1.00  2.00  2.00
    # 4     4  0     0     1.00  1.00  2.00  1.00  0     0     1.00  2.00  0     0     2.00
    # 5     5  1.00  0     0     1.00  1.00  1.00  0     0     0     3.00  2.00  0     1.00
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite a few steps!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: In @CPak's code, grouping by `rn` seems to be unnecessary. The following code also works: `tmpdf %>% mutate(rn=row_number()) %>% gather(key, value, X1:X10) %>% count(rn, value) %>% spread(value, n, fill=0)`.

Answer (score 0):

A concise approach would be

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(tmpdf)))
#   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
#V1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0  1  1  0  1
#V2 2 1 2 1 0 1 1 0 0  1  1  0  0
#V3 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1  0  1  2  2
#V4 0 0 1 1 2 1 0 0 1  2  0  0  2
#V5 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0  3  2  0  1
```

---

Or using `mtabulate` in pipe

```
tmpdf %>%
      t %>% 
      as_tibble %>%
      mtabulate
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
table(stack(as.list(as.data.frame(t(tmpdf))))[2:1])
```